# Where is the torrc file located?

Tags: configuration

What file refers to Torrc file?

In older versions there was Vidalia. And the Torrc file was named in row Torrc=~/tor-browser_en-US/Data/Tor/torrc in the file tor-browser_en-US/Data/Vidalia/vidalia.conf.

Thank you
Petr

Comment: have a look at https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#torrc

Answer (score 2):

Torrc is the tor configuration file.  In the current version of TorBrowser, it is located in
[installation directory]/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor
You can customize the tor network with this file, such as blocking exit servers from certain countries.